# How can I create a title coverpage for a MP4 video

Tags: video

I have several MP4 videos with talks given by several speakers in a scientific conference and I wanted to create a title page for each with the relevant information:

- Title of the talk
- Name of speaker
- Title of the conference
- Date
- Possibly a logo of the conference

It does not have to be fancy, I just want a simple way of inserting this cover page before each video. 
The videos will be already edited.

Thank you.

Comment: So? Did it work?  **0:-)**

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished by using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i video-in.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i coverpage.png -filter_complex
  "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]"
  -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest video-out.mp4
```

This assumes that the cover page is a single still image with an alpha channel and you want to overlay it over a video with a frame rate of 30000/1001 (NTSC rate).

Change the `-framerate` to match your input video if it is different.  If your cover page is a video then omit `-framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1`.  If the cover page does not have an alpha channel, add one by inserting e.g. `format=yuva420p,` immediately before `fade`.

This will display the logo at x,y position **10,10** for 30 seconds followed by a 1 second fade out.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/683696/398314)